# Should old questions that are marked as duplicates still lose reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, reputation

I asked a question 6 months ago, and somebody else asked the same question 5 months ago (which would make mine one month older). However, mine was marked as a duplicate. After searching on meta for why this might happen, it seems older questions can be marked as duplicates if the newer question has a better answer. However, I still lost reputation (50!) for having the duplicate question, when it was totally out of my control.

Here's my question: [Toolbar isn't tinting MenuItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557329/toolbar-isnt-tinting-menuitems)

I think if a question is marked as a duplicate, but is older than the linked "original" question, it shouldn't cause its author to lose rep.

Comment: What makes you so sure, that your question just _looses rep_, because of being marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Asking a duplicate question causes you to loose 50 rep ? I learn something new each day :-) Edit: Looking at your profile, the only rep loss I see is for a bounty...

Comment: @JonasCz, No, you don't lose reputation for having your question marked as duplicate, OP lost it because he set a bounty

Comment: It looks as though you place a bounty on that question. You lost that reputation ***as soon as*** you set the bounty.

Comment: I misread the rep count and saw that I lost the rep for the bounty, not the duplicate mark. Sorry about that!

Comment: I don't even think there is enough effort to determine what is duplicate on Stack.  I have seen dissimilar questions asked but because the OPs used the same word in their question, the later was marked duplicate with inapplicable answers annotated.  Is it the goal of Stack reviewers to pattern match words to determine duplication?  When is a question actually a duplicate?  This is difficult to always understand.

Answer (score 4):

I misread the rep count and saw that I lost the rep for the bounty, not the duplicate mark. Sorry about that!